# Connect to an Azure SQL Database through an Azure Cloud Service

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, azure

What I want to do is use a WinForms Application that connects to the Cloud Service, when I want to query data from an Azure SQL Database I want to speak to the Cloud Service which then speaks to the Database for me and gives me back what I asked for. So using the Cloud Service as the Buisness Logic as such so my Application doesn't speak to the Database directly. First of all, is this possible? If so, is there a website anyone could point me to that explains it or could they explain it themselves? 
(I use VB.NET)

Comment: This is absolutely possible and has been since, well, for years. And on the Azure site, there are several tutorials for working with data, setting up SQL Database, allowing traffic from Azure services, etc. Probably several SO questions as well. As it stands, your question is very broad, and asks for a tutorial recommendation, both off-topic for StackOverflow. But if you head to azure.com and spend some time there, this will all be crystal clear, and then you can come back with specific questions if you run into issues.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I already have a SQL Database set up and the Cloud Service set up, I just simply don't know how to connect the two together and query stuff from my WinForms application. I suppose that is what I want to find out, how to first connect to the Cloud Service, then how to use the SQL Database from the Cloud Service (which the Database is a local resource in that Service) and return data to my WinForms app... Any help is gratefully received!